# How to join two lists of different sizes, and colon seperate entries?

Tags: bash

I have a list of usernames, and a list of passwords. I need to join them together into a colon-seperated list.

The user.txt file contains something like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
```

The passwords.txt file is shorter then the user.txt file:

```
pass1
pass2
pass3
```

How can I get them to merge, so that each password is used by each username at least once, and in the following format?

```
name1:pass1
name2:pass1
name3:pass1
...
name2:pass2
name2:pass3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v OFS=":" 'FNR==NR{a[++count]=$0;next} {val=++val==count?1:val;print $0,a[val]}' passwords.txt users.txt
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution.

```
awk -v OFS=":" '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  next
}
{
  val=++val==count?1:val
  print $0,a[val]
}
' passwords.txt users.txt
```

Comment: That seems to join them, but no colon separator, which isn't the end of the world really. Thanks!

Comment: Please check now and let me know.